# Top navigation lost links

Tags: navigation, links

I've lost links in the top site navigation bar. It now looks like this:
[image: Lost navigation links]

Rather than
[image: Correct links]
Hovering over Projects0 shows just the subsite name and not the full subsite URL.

Hope someone is able to give me a pointer to a solving this. I've got the navigation set to structural and show subsites.

Thanks

Tony

Answer (score 0):

Go to Site Settings on your subsite > Look and Feel > Navigation - check the navigation for the global and current sites.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The faulty navigation bar only appears when clicking in quick links from the left navigation pane. The subsites are all set to display same as parent with the subsites box checked.

Comment: There are two structural navigation options - Are they both the same?

Structural Navigation: Display the current site, the navigation items below the current site, and the current site's siblings  

Structural Navigation: Display only the navigation items below the current site

Comment: I've gone trough all the subsites and set both the current and global to:

Comment: Structural Navigation: Display the navigation items below the current site

Comment: With subsites checked.

Comment: Good to note Site Settings is in gray bar above Sites or Site contents page.